# Serverside Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am currently playing with Angular 2. I have put together a simple front-end application that queries a backed-end application server (whose hostname is `sinatra-server`). This is a snippet of the app component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

@Component({
    selector: 'yelb',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private router: Router,
                private http:  Http
               ) {}

  stats = {};

  public appserver = `http://sinatra-server:4567`;


    getvotes(): void {
    const url = `${this.appserver}/getvotes`;
    this.http.get(url)
                .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                .subscribe(res => {console.log(res); this.votes = res})                
  }
```

Everything works fine but for some reasons I thought/assumed this code above would have been executed "server side".

When I actually try to connect to my Angular app and I click on the `GET VOTES` button (which calls the `getvotes` function) I see that the actual REST API call to `http://sinatra-server:4567/getvotes` is being executed from the client machine instead of being executed on the Angular web server.

Needless to say that the `http://sinatra-server` application server is out of reach for the client machine (i.e. it can only be accessed by the Angular web server). So the client call doesn't work.

I have started to browse around and (indeed) Angular seems to be a client side technology (my fault for overlooking it!). There appears to be an Angular Universal thingy that would allow me to run Angular server-side but, from what I am looking at, it doesn't really seem as simple as enabling a flag that says "run the code on the Angular server Vs the client". I am wondering how difficult it will be to adapt what I have done to run "server-side" but more importantly I am wondering if what I am trying to do makes any sense or I am stretching Angular to do things that it could do... but it's not the proper technology to use for this use case.

Thanks.

Comment: Angular (and others like React, Vue, ...) are primarily intended for front-end (UI). The easiest solutions would be to either make `sinatra-server` accessible from the web or create another server that handles communication between your front-end and that server

Comment: If you want your server to make a request to another server, then do just that. You don't need Angular on the server to send HTTP requests. Any server-side technology/framework/language is able to send HTTP requests.

Comment: @UnholySheep Thanks. How about this? I can host the Angular server (port 80) on an NGINX host whose FQDN is `myapp.com`. I can then modify the Angular function above to run the HTTP GET against `http://myapp.com/getstats`. The NGINX server would be configured to proxy `http://myapp.com:80/getstats` to `http://sinatra-server:4567/getstats`. Would this work and, more importantly, would this be a proper pattern for an Angular deployment? Thanks.